# What is difference between File Based Encryption(FBE) and Full Disk Encryption(FDE)

Tags: android, encryption, linux-kernel

From Android N, new feature FBE (File Based encryption) was introduced. How it is different from FDE (Full Disk Encryption).

How can I verify whether my Android device has FBE?

Comment: Here is excellent topic: https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/11/24/android-n-encryption/ .

Answer (score 5):

Different from encrypting full disk, file based encryption can encrypt each file via different keys. The most noticeable usage is that different user profile now using different keys. Previously, different users share the same disk encryption key.

OK, user/developer visible change is that we will have a so-called direct boot feature. Previously after rebooting, a user has to unlock the entire disk (same password as the primary user), on a black screen with password input, and then unlock his own profile (mostly primary user). Now, you can reboot directly to user profile unlock. No black screen unlocking any more. For developer, you can run your app in user0 space which doesn't require user's profile unlocked. That means your app can run before user input their password and swipe to unlock.

More info can be found [android official doc](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with FBE vs. FDE is that it doesn't give you the ability to have two separate passwords one for boot (longer) and another for screen (shorter). In FBE you are either forced to have one long or one short password: long one is inconvenient, as you have to enter it every time to unlock and short one is less secure.